# Azure Face Identify more than 10 faces in a Person Group

Tags: limit, azure-cognitive-services, face, identify

So, a **straightforward** question. My first on SO. Asking here because it says so on the Azure Docs to ask here.

I understand that the Face API can identify at most 10 faces in an API call. Is it possible to get this limit raised to, say, 50? Maybe through some specific pricing agreement?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

I see the best way to do this is by handling it on your side, maybe by dividing your 50 faces image into 5 pieces where each piece will have 10 faces, then make an API call for each piece, noting that the paid tier is limited to 10 calls per second, so, if you have more than 10 pieces you'll have to put them in a queue and have the view load the results using the async/await pattern or just load for a few seconds until you have all the results to present and use.

Comment: I've used faceIDs from faceDetect instead of an image url, and I just search for 10 faces at a time using subsequent calls. Thanks for your reply 

Comment: That's the only way to do it but if you can increase the amount from 10 to 20, this will decrease the number of requests you make where the operation will complete faster but more importantly it will be cheaper as you are being charged by the number of requests you make.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the cognitive services for a while and didn't found a way to increase some of the hard limits even after some discussions with representatives from MS (if you can find the right person they are very helpful, but it's hard to find the right person :). Similar to the 10 person limit, you also can't change 24 hour face keeping duration. At least we were not able to find it.

Of course this case only true for using the scenario of Create PersonList, Detect Image and Identify. If you just use identification using face list, you don't have this limit as you have the ability to save those faces in a face list and then query them which will search the whole list even if it's 10 or 100 faces.